# How to make a program which would be record keyboard

Tags: java, keyboard, recorder

I have an idea.
I want to make a program that should be able to record every key that has been pressed during it program has been running.
I want to ask, is it possible to manage this using java or i need something else.
What is more can you recomend me some ways how to manage this easier and what exactly i need  to use. 
Thank you very much. Im waiting for your answer soon.

Comment: Do you need the java program to continue scan for inputs when it is out of focus?

Comment: Yes, what is more i want it to save every input in a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to listen for keystroke outside the focus of your java program if you are using packages from Java itself. You may have to use external packages which is able to communicate with the operating system.

I tried something similar years ago, but not by using Java. What you wanted to do can be easily achieved using AHK ([Auto Hotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)) - A free open source scripting language.

If you still want to write a Java application, you may write the application in Java and let it execute `.ahk` script to handle the key logging for you.

Comment: Im begginer in programming, I have tried only java in game programming and Im not sure that im able to manage this by myself. can you help me with some more advices ?

Comment: @LetsBuildGames AHK is actually much easier than Java itself, after all, it is a scripting language. I made my key logger in 5 minutes. As compared to languages like C++ or Java... it would not possible to be done in 5 minutes. Furthermore, you may have to handle issues such as threading by yourself.

Comment: I have no idea about AHK? I can use it with no expierience?

Comment: Yes, I have seen many kids less than 12 years old playing with it. If you can ask a question on coding a key logger in Java, I see no reason you can't do it in AHK.

Comment: Can you recommend me any text editor for ahk ? Its open by default notepad.

Comment: Is better tutorials on youtube or tutorials on the official site are enough?

Comment: For me I only use the tutorial provided by them, you can also open some of their sample codes. They provide very good help file with good documentation.